# Behavior overrides event handling from MVVM

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, desktop-application, attachedbehaviors

I'm modifying an application which uses WPF and MVVM but also Behaviors in some places. I need to apply a drag Behavior (for a GUI element which will be a Drag&Drop origin) but when I connect a GUI element with a Behavior...

```
<i:Interaction.Behaviors>
  <behaviors:FrameworkElementDragBehavior/>
</i:Interaction.Behaviors>
```

...it then starts to ignore the functions which handle events in the ViewModel (which are `RelayCommand` and are `Bind` targets in XAML tag attributes). How to have both - the handlers in the ViewModel and in the Behavior?

Comment: could you please post a verifiable example? thanks. P.S. Also take a look at [this](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/420545/WPF-Drag-and-Drop-MVVM-using-Behavior) if it can help you

Comment: Too much code to post here. But I guess, my other question also is whether this is normal and I need to completely change the concept or if it's not normal, should I be looking for a bug somewhere in the code?

Comment: In fact I was asking to create a *Minimal* but Complete, and Verifiable [example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)